# Github Docker workflow fails without error message

Tags: docker, github, workflow, github-actions

I am using the [`docker-publish.yml`](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/ci/docker-publish.yml) Github workflow to build and publish a Docker image on Github. The image is built successfully, but the workflow fails at the "Post Build and push Docker image" without any error message. Here is a [link](https://github.com/ahmedmoustafa/bioinformatics-toolbox/actions/runs/927764499) to the run, including the logs. It might be the size of the image, but I cannot tell. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try following the [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md) from the [docker/build-and-push](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images) action? Moreover, is there a reason why you used actions specific versions in [your workflow](https://github.com/ahmedmoustafa/bioinformatics-toolbox/blob/main/.github/workflows/docker-publish.yml)?

Comment: The troubleshooting section does not seem to include that issue (there is no error message). Regarding the specific versions, it was the workflow generated "By GitHub Actions".

Comment: The push worked fine from the command line `docker push ghcr.io/ahmedmoustafa/bioinformatics-tools` and it is available through the Github [registry](https://github.com/users/ahmedmoustafa/packages/container/package/bioinformatics-tools), but the workflow action is still failing.